# Regex to match strings that does not contain standalone numbers

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following example of strings.

```
Mr 1
Mr Ace The 3rd
Mr James 2
Mr 299
Mr Seth
```

All of them starts with the word **Mr**

I want to write a regex which matches the strings with no standalone numbers which are

```
Mr Ace the 3rd
Mr James 2
Mr Seth
```

and

```
Mr 1
Mr 299
```

in this case should be ignored since they only consists of **standalone numbers** after the Mr

Currently I tried something like:

```
^(Mr\s)(.*\D)$
```

but it seems to not be matching Mr James 2. How do i get it to only ignore the strings with standalone number after the **Mr** ?

Comment: Would you please explain what does it mean *the strings with no standalone numbers*?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead pattern to exclude standalone numbers after `Mr` :

```
^Mr\s(?!\d+$).*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/27oZLW/1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match only `Mr` you could match 1+ whitespace chars followed by matching at least a single non whitspace char other than a digit.

```
^Mr\s+[^\d\s].*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yc4PQU/1)